# What is the most effective way to copy cells from one Sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I am working on a Report of reports. That means; I have a main report `(sheet 'Rm')` that will hold the result values from the rest of the sub reports  `(sheet 'Rs_1'....'Rs_n')`.

`Rm` will write only 2 columns from each of the `Rs_i` and it will be pasted sequentially to the right side for each sub report(Rs) found.

Since there is more than 100,000 cells and more the 100 sub-reports to copy and paste I would like to optimize the best way possible the timing for that.

So my question is. What is the most optimized way by vba to copy the columns `Worksheets(Rs_1).(Range("B14:B500;F14:F500")` from `worksheets(Rs_1).Range("A14:F500")` into the two(2) followed columns in the Main Report:  `Worksheets(Rm).Range("E15:F501")`

```vb
For Each i_Rs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If i_Rs.Name = mainReportName Then
        'do Nothing on Main Report
    Else
        '-->take report's Order Nr and Part Nr
        i_Rs_Nr = GetNumeric(i_Rs.Range(Rs_NrPosRng).Value)
        i_Rs_PartNr = GetNumeric(i_Rs.Range(Rs_ParNrPosRng).Value)
                    
        '-->get Rs big Range
        Set i_Rs_BigRng = FindStringRng("A:H", "Characteristic", i_Rs.Name)
        Set i_Rs_BigRng = Range(i_Rs_BigRng, i_Rs_BigRng.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
            
        '-->set the actual range of MainReport to paste value from
        For j_Rm = 1 To Rm_BigRng.row Step 2 ' loop on every two columns
            Set j_RmRng = Range(Rm_BigRng(1, 1), Rm_BigRng(qtyCharacsRows, 2))
            '************************************************
            '*** HERE logic to take the sub from each report and copy-paste values
            '************************************************
            Set j_RmPartNrRng = Range(Rm_BigRng(1, 1), Rm_BigRng(1, 1))
            Set j_RmPartNrRng = Cells(j_RmRng.row - 2, j_RmRng.Column + 1)
            '-->write part number into j_Rm
            j_RmPartNrRng.Value = i_Rs_PartNr
            '**** get sub range for each Rs
            Set i_Rs_BigRng = Range(i_Rs_BigRng(2, 1), i_Rs_BigRng(qtyCharacsRows + 1, i_Rs_BigRng.Columns.count)) ' Need optimization to erase first row
            Set i_Rs_subRng = Union(i_Rs_BigRng.Columns(2), i_Rs_BigRng.Columns(6)) ' need columns in letters
                                      
            '*** Copy Rs("B:B,F:F").values into Rm("E:F").values
            j_RmRng.Value = i_Rs_subRng.Value 'Error: the first column is copying good the second is just a copy of the first
        Next j_Rm   
    End If       
Next
```

Comment: Can you post your existing code?

Comment: Im am coding in the rest of the logic , preparing the data , setting the main ranges etc. The code does not need to loop from each sub report (this I will do). just to copy as I suggested from only one sheet to the main range. Thank a lot for your time... when I develop the rest I will post it

Comment: I have posted the code.. can you reopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need cell formatting then the fastest way would be to avoid `Range.Copy` entirely and just directly pass values using arrays.

When a Range contains more than one cell, Range.Value returns an array of variant values which you can put back into a worksheet by setting a different Range.Value = Array. In this case, since you don't actually need to manipulate or process the values, you can skip the array and directly do `Range1.Value = Range2.Value` which transfers all values *as long as the ranges are the same size*.

So as far as I know, the fastest way to transfer the data would be `Range1.Value = Range2.Value`.

For your code:

```vb
Worksheets(Rm).Range("E15:F501").Value = Worksheets(Rs_1).Range("B14:B500,F14:F500").Value
```

Comment: Hi Toddleson I will try that probably is that what I need. Just one question Ho do I get a subRange of the Rm range. I need Rm.Range(501R x 2C) from Worksheets(Rm).Range("E15:F501")  a mean just two columns

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by subrange. `Worksheets(Rm).Range("E15:F501")` is a range with 487 rows and 2 columns. If you want to reference a specific row you can use `.Rows(x)` where x is the row number. It starts counting from the first cell of the range so x=1 would give you Range("E15:F15"). You would write it like `Worksheets(Rm).Range("E15:F501").Rows(1)`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: I want somthing like this. Set i_Rs_subRng = Union(i_Rs_BigRng("B:B"), i_Rs_BigRng("F:F")). In munites ill try to post the code.

Comment: When you are using named columns in a defined range, you should be aware that "B:B" will not be the "B:B" on the sheet but rather the second column of the range. So if your range is "B:F" then MyRange.Range("B:B") will return the second column aka "C:C"